# php dealing with apache rewrite urls in the code

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting

in my application i'm currently using "pretty urls" with apache rewrite. So:

> article.php?id=123&title=hello-bob

becomes:

> /articles/hello-bob.123

In my local dev environment, I'm not using pretty urls and I ended up writing a function to pass links through, to get the correct one based on a setting:

```
public function get_link($id, $title, $additional = NULL)
{
    $link = '';
    $nice_title = core::nice_title($title); // remove spaces, special characters and so on so-it-looks-like-this

    if ($this->config('pretty_urls') == 1)
    {
        $link = 'articles/'.$nice_title.'.'.$id;

        if ($additional != NULL)
        {
            $link = $link . '/' . $additional;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $link = 'index.php?module=articles_full&aid='.$id.'&title='.$nice_title;

        if ($additional != NULL)
        {
            $link = $link . '&' . $additional;
        }
    }
    return $this->config('website_url') . $link;
}
```

Is this really wasteful? I'm wondering how other applications and sites manage this, when they allow people to enable pretty urls and show the correct links in the rendered content?

Comment: Generally you'd use a [PHP/.htaccess router](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049) to punt everything to `index.php` and a routing table of *"pretty" -> real* URLs in the database. `index.php` then just grabs your "pretty" URL from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and fetches the real resource URL from the routing table.